# how to check whether an element is a child of a specific parent in cypress.io

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to do some checks on an element but also check whether it's located in a specific parent.
here is part of original code:

```
  it("shows right panel elements", () => {
    cy.get(selectors.rightPanel).find(selectors.logo)
    cy.get(selectors.rightPanel)
      .find(selectors.menuBar)
      .find(selectors.wishlistIcon)
      .closest("a")
      .should("have.attr", "href", selectors.wishlistUrl)
      .should("be.visible")
    cy.get(selectors.rightPanel)
      .find(selectors.menuBar)
      .find(selectors.cartIcon)
      .closest("a")
      .should("have.attr", "href", selectors.cartUrl)
      .should("be.visible")
  })
```

My colleagues told me to avoid chaining with `find` to prevent flakiness.
I have tried to use within, but it looks quite ugly, especially if I need to go multiple levels down.

```
cy.get(selectors.rightPanel).within($panel => {
  cy.get(selectors.logo)
  cy.get(selectors.menuBar)
  cy.get(selectors.logo)
  cy.get(selectors.wishlistIcon)
    .closest("a")
    .should("have.attr", "href", selectors.wishlistUrl)
    .and("be.visible")
}).
```

what would be a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Presume the nesting is something like

```js
<rightPanel>
  <menuBar>
    <wishlistIcon>
```

You could use this to specifically test the child-parent relationship

```
cy.get(selectors.wishlistIcon)
  .parents(selectors.menuBar)   // does wishlistIcon have a parent with menuBar selector?
```

but I see nothing wrong with

```
cy.get(selectors.rightPanel)
  .find(selectors.menuBar)       // find within rightPanel
  .find(selectors.wishlistIcon)  // find within menuBar
```

and this is the better direction to go since you want the `href` to be part of the story.

I can't see why `find` might be considered flakey. It has a `timeout` option, which means it has the Cypress retry mechanism (the primary defense against flakiness).

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to fully grasp the problem from your code but the below command from the dom API might do the trick

```
Cypress.dom.isChild(possibleChild, possibleParent);
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Cypress.dom.isChild` is not exposed on the Cypress.dom api. Although it is in the source [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/bd71274f61facb2c9c71037fbe68d1506e55e4ba/packages/driver/src/dom/elements.ts#L651)  and exported in that file, it's not re-exported.